# Is it possible to have flask api running on apache with already running PHP site for same domain?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, flask-restful

Is is possible to run flask rest api in apache + ubuntu server where already PHP website is running with that domain??

in short: if I browse url [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) then normal php website should load. if I call [www.example.com/services/api](http://www.example.com/services/api) then flask api should give result....

**Updated => Answer**
Finally I found a solution, posting here if it can help someone...
(Ubuntu Server)

-->with root (Assuming Python and Pip already installed)

1. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 python3-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
3. `pip3 install virtualenv`

-->with domain user
navigate to folder where you want to create virtual environment... then type below command (you can change virtual environment name according to your need)

1. `python3 -m virtualenv myenv` <-(any name)
2. activate environment with command `source myenv/bin/activate`
3. install flask with commend `pip install flask`
4. create file  below data--> `flaskapp.wsgi` in project folder or anywhere you want... then following code

```
import logging
 import sys

activate_this = '/your/envfolder/path/bin/activate_this.py'

exec(compile(open(activate_this).read(), activate_this, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/your/app/folder/path/where/you/can/import/app')
from App import app as application
#application.secret_key = 'anything-you-wish'
```

Finally with  `etc/apache2/sites_available` and your `sitename.conf` add below code...

```
WSGIScriptAlias /your/wsgi/folderpath/flaskapp.wsgi
    <Directory /your/wsgi/folderpath/>
        # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
        allow from all
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

**Note:** *This is how I made it to work... I am not a professional server developer, I am not sure if this is a right way to do it...*

Comment: Probably. Why not? Did you try? What happened?

Comment: I know to host flask app seperately by installing and configuring mod_wsgi and configuring apache2/sites-available/website.conf

but i dont know how to update website.conf already used by php for same domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is possible. You will need to specify a certain route for each app.

For example,

foo.com/ -> PHP
foo.com/api -> Flask App

A sample apache config would be something like this:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName foo.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ProxyPass /  http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 
  ProxyPassReverse /  http://127.0.0.1:8080/

  ProxyPass /api/  http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse /api/  http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... is there anything needs to do in Flask side..?

Comment: You just need to serve the flask app. "flask run" if you using the new flask and you will need to set the env variables to point to the flask app