# How to configure Apache to both serve web page AND host REST API?

Tags: python, apache, api, https, flask-restful

I am going from a prototype environment where I have written an API in Python using Flask, and have been testing it through Python's `http.client` module, to a web accessible, production environment where I am trying to access the API using jquery, and I have run into the below problems

1. Local `.html` file could not make HTTP GET/POST requests, so I switched to serving the files with Apache2 at `/var/www/html` (using my global IP, eg. `https://59.59.59.59`)
2. Browser refused to load unencrypted connections so I switched to using self signed certificates in Apache2
3. Now browser refuses to call the API because I believe it refuses to use a different port for the API (web page served on `443` but the API running on `12345`) because it treats it as a different URL (`net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`). I tried changing the port from `12345` to `443` in Python Flask but it crashed the API, probably because Apache is already listening on that port.

Tutorials on Python API's don't seem to address this and assume that the endpoints will magically work out of the box. Is there something I must configure in Apache to make the endpoints accessible over HTTPS? The only thing I can think of is that I have to somehow route my global IP address on some trigger (eg. `https://59.59.59.59/api/<api_endpoint>`) to the appropriate API endpoint and port (eg. `127.0.0.1:12345/<api_endpoint>`. Is this the right way to do it? If so, how?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030843/is-it-possible-to-have-flask-api-running-on-apache-with-already-running-php-site

Comment: @Rabbitminers Yes, thank you